# VBA Excel Finding and Combining Rows Based on Matching Column Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to figure out a way to combine rows based on values in two specific columns in vba excel.
For Example:
Let's say I have the following sheet:

```
Column A   Column J   Column Z
    1         A          ?
    1         A          !
    2         B          ?
    2         B          !
```

And I need to convert it to this:

```
Column A   Column J   Column Z
    1         A         ?, !
    2         B         ?, !
```

Comment: You might need a Pivot Table: http://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another method using User Defined Types and collections to iterate through the list and develop the combined results.  For large sets of data, it should be **considerably** faster than reading through each cell on the worksheet.

I assume that you are grouping on Col J, and that Column A data does not need to be concatenated in the cell.  If it does, the modifications to the routine would be trivial.

First, Insert a **Class Module**, rename it **CombData** and insert the following code into that module:

```
Option Explicit
Private pColA As String
Private pColJ As String
Private pColZConcat As String

Public Property Get ColA() As String
    ColA = pColA
End Property
Public Property Let ColA(Value As String)
    pColA = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ColJ() As String
    ColJ = pColJ
End Property
Public Property Let ColJ(Value As String)
    pColJ = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ColZConcat() As String
    ColZConcat = pColZConcat
End Property
Public Property Let ColZConcat(Value As String)
    pColZConcat = Value
End Property
```

Then Insert a Regular Module and insert the Code Below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineData()
    Dim cCombData As CombData
    Dim colCombData As Collection
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant 'Results Array
    Dim rRes As Range   'Location of results
    Dim I As Long

'read source data into array
V = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=26)

'Set results range.  Here it is set below the Source Data
'Could be anyplace, even on a different worksheet; or could overlay the
'  original.  Area below and to right is cleared

Set rRes = Range("A1").Offset(UBound(V) + 10)
Range(rRes, rRes.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Clear

Set colCombData = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    Set cCombData = New CombData
    cCombData.ColA = V(I, 1)
    cCombData.ColJ = V(I, 10)
    cCombData.ColZConcat = V(I, 26)
    colCombData.Add cCombData, CStr(cCombData.ColJ)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        With colCombData(cCombData.ColJ)
            .ColZConcat = .ColZConcat & ", " & V(I, 26)
        End With
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

ReDim vRes(1 To colCombData.Count, 1 To 26)
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes)
    With colCombData(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .ColA
        vRes(I, 10) = .ColJ
        vRes(I, 26) = .ColZConcat
    End With
Next I

rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2)) = vRes

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Note that the source data is read into the Variant array **V**.  If you examine V in the Watch Window, you will see that the first dimension represents the rows; and the second dimension the columns.  So if you wanted, for example, to perform the same procedure on a different set of columns, you would merely change the references to the second dimension under the line that reads Set cCombData = New CombData.  For example, column B data would be V(I,2), and so forth.  Of course, you might want to rename the data types to make them more representative of what you are doing.

In addition, if your data starts at row 2, merely start the iteration through V with I = 2 instead of I = 1.

**EDIT2:**  In order to both overwrite the original, and also maintain the contents of the columns not being processed, the following modification will do that for Columns A, J and Z.  You should be able to modify it for whatever columns you choose to process.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineData()
    Dim cCombData As CombData
    Dim colCombData As Collection
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant 'Results Array
    Dim rRes As Range   'Location of results
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

'read source data into array
V = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=26)

'Set results range.  Here it is set below the Source Data
'Could be anyplace, even on a different worksheet; or could overlay the
'  original.  Area below and to right is cleared

Set rRes = Range("A1")  '.Offset(UBound(V) + 10)
Range(rRes, rRes.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Clear

Set colCombData = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    Set cCombData = New CombData
    cCombData.ColA = V(I, 1)
    cCombData.ColJ = V(I, 10)
    cCombData.ColZConcat = V(I, 26)
    colCombData.Add cCombData, CStr(cCombData.ColJ)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        With colCombData(cCombData.ColJ)
            .ColZConcat = .ColZConcat & ", " & V(I, 26)
        End With
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

ReDim vRes(1 To colCombData.Count, 1 To 26)
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes)
    With colCombData(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .ColA
        vRes(I, 10) = .ColJ
        vRes(I, 26) = .ColZConcat

        'Note the 10 below is the column we are summarizing by
        J = WorksheetFunction.Match(.ColJ, WorksheetFunction.Index(V, 0, 10), 0)
        For K = 1 To 26
            Select Case K  'Decide which columns to copy over
                Case 2 To 9, 11 To 25
                    vRes(I, K) = V(J, K)
            End Select
        Next K
    End With
Next I

rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2)) = vRes

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm looking for! One more question, I have another sheet I would like to apply this same exact Procedure to, however the columns are different. What would I need to change for Columns B, J, and R respectively. Also, the data in this particular sheet starts on the second row.

Comment: @user3891378 Glad to help. And I would appreciate it if you would mark as the answer. I will Edit my response so as to provide you with the answer to the question about your other worksheet.

Comment: Ok so I changed the results range to overlay the current sheet. I guess I forgot to mention that there is also data in Columns A-U that I would like to retain as well.Right now it just deletes everything except whats in those columns.

Comment: One simple way to do that would be to copy the data from a row in V to the row in vRes.  Since you are summarizing based on Col_J, to determine which row from V to copy, you could just do a MATCH to get the correct row.  I'll post in my response.

Comment: Ok, so this works great for a small amount of data. I just tried applying it to a very large set of data (8000 rows) and ran into some problems. First, it deletes everything in the entire sheet. Secondly, it gets hung up and crashes giving an error message about index for WorksheetFunction failing.

Comment: @user3891378 It's not clear that those problems are different.  Depending on the error message, perhaps you are checking the wrong column in the Index function.

Comment: Any idea why Range(rRes, rRes.SpecialCells(xlCellT ypeLastCell)).Clear is deleting everything?

Comment: @user3891378 It is designed to do that, so you can overwrite the previous results.  Since you are setting rRes= [a1], it will clear everything from A1 to the last cell; i.e. all of the cells.  You wanted to overwrite the original, remember?

Comment: Right, i guess it just never gets the chance to overwrite the original because it crashes here: j = WorksheetFunction.Match(.ColJ, WorksheetFunction.Index(V, 0, 10), 0)

Comment: "Method Index of Object Worksheet Failed"

Comment: @user3891378 Exactly.  And that is where the problem lies.  Can you post a copy of the dysfunctional workbook (with confidential information removed), so I can figure out why that line is crashing with that error?  There are various public sites and you can post a link here. I suspect there is either something about the data, or something about how you've adapted the code to the changes in your requirements, that is responsible.

Comment: `Set colCombData = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    Set cCombData = New CombData
    cCombData.ColA = V(I, 2)
    cCombData.ColJ = V(I, 10)
    cCombData.ColZConcat = V(I, 18)
    colCombData.Add cCombData, CStr(cCombData.ColJ)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        With colCombData(cCombData.ColJ)
            .ColZConcat = .ColZConcat & ", " & V(I, 18)
        End With
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: basically i just changed a few columns. (2, 10, and 18) respectively

Comment: @user3891378 I don't see a link to the workbook in what you posted.

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but it seems unlikely that its the actual data itself. It works perfectly for a small subset of the data but not for the whole thing. Here's some more code that ive changed:

Comment: `ReDim vRes(1 To colCombData.Count, 1 To 26)
>For I = 2 To UBound(vRes)
With colCombData(I)
vRes(I, 2) = .ColB
vRes(I, 10) = .ColJ
vRes(I, 18) = .ColRConcat
        
        Dim test As Integer
        
        test = colCombData.Count
        
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        
        j = WorksheetFunction.Match(.ColJ, WorksheetFunction.Index(V, 0, 10), 0)
For k = 1 To 21
Select Case k  'Decide which columns to copy over
Case 1, 3 To 9, 11 To 17, 19 To 21
vRes(I, k) = V(j, k)
End Select
Next k     
End With
Next I`

Comment: @user3891378 It could be an undocumented limitation.  But, it is unlikely I will be able to help you without access to data and code that reproduces the problem.  I cannot reproduce the problem here by duplicating what you have shown for 8000+ rows.  Posting code in comments is singularly unhelpful

Comment: I apologize, I am very unfamiliar with both VBA excel and Stackoverflow. I'm also not sure how I would link my workbook to you.

Comment: @user3891378 There are free sites such as OneDrive, DropBox and others which allow you to post files and share them by sharing a link.

Comment: @user3891378 I tried taking a look at the code you posted in the comments, but there are too many differences from what I originally posted for me to comment.  Again, I need functioning material that demonstrates the problem to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that Column J is the key and Column A doesn't need to be appended.  If Column A needs to be combined as well (not always the same), you would simply need to add another for each loop to check if the data is there, and add it if not, as done for col 26 in the code.

```
Sub CombineData()

    x = 2
    Do Until Cells(x, 1) = "" 'loop through every row in sheet starting at 2 (1 will never be removed, since it is the first data)
        x2 = 1
        Do Until x2 = x
            If Cells(x, 10) = Cells(x2, 10) Then 'this is comparing column J.  If another column is the reference then change 10 to the column number

                splt = Split(Cells(x, 26), ", ")
                For Each s In splt 'check to see if data already in column z
                    If s = Cells(x2, 26) Then GoTo alreadyEntered
                Next

                Cells(x, 26) = Cells(x, 26) & ", " & Cells(x2, 26) 'append column z data to row x
alreadyEntered:
                Rows(x2).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete duplicate row
                x = x - 1 'to keep x at same row, since we just removed a row
                Exit Do
            Else
                x2 = x2 + 1
            End If

        Loop

        x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Are splt and s Range datatypes?

Comment: splt and s are just variables.  I always use splt to contain the array when I'm splitting something if it will be immediately used, and s for a string variable when it doesn't need to be used in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very new to VBA. What do you mean by 'just variables'? I get a compiler error about those variables not being defined.

Comment: You must have option explicit chosen.  At the beginning of the sub, just add the line - Dim s, splt