# Key is already associated with an element

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this macro for over two years.  Nothing changed until I had an update from Microsoft.   Now I'm receiving Error 457 - this key is already aossicated with an element of this collection.  I posted the class module as well as the macro.  The error is caused by the code "colCombData.Add cCombData, CStr(cCombData.ColA)"    Can anyone shed some light as to how to correct this issue.

```
Option Explicit
Private pColA As String
Private pColB As String
Private pColCConcat As String
Private pColHConcat As String
Private pColIConcat As String
Private pColJConcat As String
Private pColKConcat As String
Private pColLConcat As String
'step 1 A
Public Property Get ColA() As String
    ColA = pColA
End Property
'step 2 A
Public Property Let ColA(Value As String)
    pColA = Value
End Property

'step 1 B
Public Property Get ColB() As String
    ColB = pColB
End Property
'step 2 B
Public Property Let ColB(Value As String)
    pColB = Value
End Property

'step 1 concat C
Public Property Get ColCConcat() As String
    ColCConcat = pColCConcat
End Property

'step 2 concat C
Public Property Let ColCConcat(Value As String)
    pColCConcat = Value
End Property

'step 1 concat H
Public Property Get ColHConcat() As String
    ColHConcat = pColHConcat
End Property

'step 2 concat H
Public Property Let ColHConcat(Value As String)
    pColHConcat = Value
End Property

'step 1 concat J
Public Property Get ColJConcat() As String
    ColJConcat = pColJConcat
End Property

'step 2 concat J
Public Property Let ColJConcat(Value As String)
    pColJConcat = Value
End Property

'step 1 concat I
Public Property Get ColIConcat() As String
    ColIConcat = pColIConcat
End Property

'step 2 concat I
Public Property Let ColIConcat(Value As String)
    pColIConcat = Value
End Property

'step 1 concat K
Public Property Get ColKConcat() As String
    ColKConcat = pColKConcat
End Property

'step 2 concat K
Public Property Let ColKConcat(Value As String)
    pColKConcat = Value
End Property

'step 1 concat L
Public Property Get ColLConcat() As String
    ColLConcat = pColLConcat
End Property

'step 2 concat L
Public Property Let ColLConcat(Value As String)
    pColLConcat = Value
End Property


    Option Explicit
Sub CombineData()
    Dim cCombData As Combdata
    Dim colCombData As Collection
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant 'Results Array
    Dim rRes As Range   'Location of results
    Dim I As Long

'read source data into array
V = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=13)

'Set results range.  Here it is set below the Source Data
'Could be anyplace, even on a different worksheet; or could overlay the
'  original.  Area below and to right is cleared
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set rRes = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")

Range(rRes, rRes.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Clear

'code to grab all data that will be used
Set colCombData = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    Set cCombData = New Combdata
    cCombData.ColA = V(I, 1)
    cCombData.ColB = V(I, 2)
    cCombData.ColCConcat = V(I, 3)
    cCombData.ColHConcat = V(I, 7)
    cCombData.ColIConcat = V(I, 8)
    cCombData.ColJConcat = V(I, 9)
    cCombData.ColKConcat = V(I, 10)
    cCombData.ColLConcat = V(I, 11)
    colCombData.Add cCombData, CStr(cCombData.ColA) < ---Error line

    'if statement to concatenate specified columns
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        With colCombData(cCombData.ColA)
            .ColCConcat = .ColCConcat & ", " & Chr(10) & V(I, 3)
            .ColHConcat = .ColHConcat & ", " & Chr(10) & V(I, 7)
            .ColIConcat = .ColIConcat & ", " & Chr(10) & V(I, 8)
            .ColJConcat = .ColJConcat & ", " & Chr(10) & V(I, 9)
            .ColKConcat = .ColKConcat & ", " & Chr(10) & V(I, 10)
            .ColLConcat = .ColLConcat & ", " & Chr(10) & V(I, 11)
        End With
    End If
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'code to write new data in specified location
ReDim vRes(1 To colCombData.Count, 1 To 13)
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes)
    With colCombData(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .ColA
        vRes(I, 2) = .ColB
        vRes(I, 3) = .ColCConcat
        vRes(I, 7) = .ColHConcat
        vRes(I, 8) = .ColIConcat
        vRes(I, 9) = .ColJConcat
        vRes(I, 10) = .ColKConcat
        vRes(I, 11) = .ColLConcat
    End With
Next I

rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2)) = vRes


'formatting
 With rRes


  .Range("A1:K1").Interior.ColorIndex = 48
  .Range("A1:K1").Font.Bold = True

  .Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=13).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
  .Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=11).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
  .Range("A1:K1").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  .Range("A1:K1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Columns("a:a").ColumnWidth = 16.57
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 13.71
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 8.43
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 7.29
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 15.43
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 45
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 13.57
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 15.43
    Rows(2).RowHeight = 100
    .Range("D:F").EntireColumn.Delete
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in column A of `Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=13)`?

Comment: Yes, there are duplicate values.  I've used this macro for quite sometime and just yesterday this error came.  Nothing has changed in the way I've used this.  However, yesterday I had an update from Microsoft and at that point this error occurs.

Comment: If there are duplicates in column A it's going to throw an error. You are using that value as the key for your collection and a collection key must be unique in that collection. Otherwise it's a terrible key, right?

Comment: Your `On Error Resume Next` should ignore the duplicate key error and skip to the next line, so maybe you've changed your error trapping option to "break on all errors"?  In the VB editor look under tools >> options

Comment: The duplicates in column A are what is determining the concatenation of the other fields.  This worked perfectly until yesterday.  I've used this same report for 2 years.

Comment: Did you check your error handling settings?

Comment: The person that worked with me to create this macro, used this solution.  It worked until I had an update from Microsoft.  I can't figure it out.  Mine has a few more columns to concatenate but basically the same macro
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036658/vba-excel-finding-and-combining-rows-based-on-matching-column-cells

Comment: I  misspoke about duplicates in Column A, there are no duplicated, but there are empty cells. The data created is from a pivot table and column A has the The data that is unique which is what tells the macro to concatenate up to the next unique data.